# Jquery append not giving correct optgroup

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery append which should wrap an optgroup label around each year. However, my output is not reflecting this.  Is there a better way to add this to my select?

```
if (year) {
    if ($('option[value="' + year.titleid  + '"]').length == 0) {
        $(titleselect).append('<optgroup label="' + year.category + '">');
        $(titleselect).append($('<option>', {
            value: year.titleid,
            text: year.name
        }));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<optgroup label="Tailoring"></optgroup>
    <option value="27472">Suits</option>
```

Comment: If the option should be a child of the optgroup, you just have to change your logic to do that.  You are appending to the titleselect both times

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice, got this working now.

```
$(titleselect).append($('<optgroup>').prop('label', year.acyr)
                        .append($('<option>', {
                           value: year.titleid,
                           text: year.name
                        }))
                );
```